# How to perform matrix equality?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I have two matrices. A with size 160 x 250 and B with size 3200 x 250.

I want to get the set intersection of each row of A with each row of B to get a 160 x 3200 vector. (The set size is 250 elements)

Any ideas how to implement this?

I'm thinking it should require torch.eq, but not sure how to change the dimensions. For example:

result = torch.sum(torch.eq(A[0], B), dim=1) would give me a 3200 element vector comparison with just the 0th row of A. I want for all rows of A (160)

Comment: `"I want to get the set intersection"`, can you explain what you mean by set intersection?

Comment: Basically I want this:

Comment: I want this: result = torch.sum(torch.eq(A[0], B), dim=1) except for all rows of A and not just 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to check equality between the `160x3200` possible pairs of 250-feature vectors. You can do so with an indexing trick:

```
>>> (A[None] == B[:, None]).all(-1)
```